# How can I execute functions asynchronously?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have simple code like this. I get warnings that the message processing is slow, and to consider offloading data handling to another thread.

So I am trying to call HandleBuy/SellOrder functions in an async manner. How can I do this? Because these methods do not return anything. I just want them to do their thing in an async manner. What's the most efficient way to do this?

What confuses me is if I mark the methods as async, the IDE says because I don't use await, they will run synchronously. But if I await that means that thread will wait until the function finishes? Because I don't want that. I want those functions to do their thing in another thread without blocking the main thread.

Also if I mark the methods as async then I have to return a Task? Because I don't have a Task to return. It's just some operations that needs to be done in the background.

```
    socketClient.Spot.SubscribeToUserDataUpdatesAsync ( spotListenKey.Result.Data,
        // Order update
        data =>
        {
            // Order update
            string symbol = Utility.GetBaseSymbol ( data.Symbol );
            if ( data.Side == OrderSide.Buy )
                Utility.HandleBuyOrder ( data );
            else if ( data.Side == OrderSide.Sell )
                Utility.HandleSellOrder ( data );
        },
        // OCO updates
        null,
        // Position updates
        null,
        // Balance updates
        null
        );

public static void HandleBuyOrder ( BinanceStreamOrderUpdate data )
{
    if ( data.Status == OrderStatus.Filled || data.Status == OrderStatus.Canceled || data.Status == OrderStatus.New )
    {
        if ( data.QuantityFilled > 0 )
        {
            var pairSymbol = Utility.GetPairSymbol ( data.Symbol );
            if ( pairSymbol != "" )
                MarketData.UpdateStableCoinBalance ( pairSymbol );

            string order = String.Format ( "{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}", data.Symbol, data.Price, data.QuantityFilled, data.QuoteQuantityFilled, data.OrderId, data.EventTime );
            Utility.AddCoinToOrderLogs ( order, data.OrderId );

            var newAction = new UpdateAction ( UpdateType.NewCoinAdded, data.Symbol );
            Utility.UpdateActions.Enqueue ( newAction );

            Console.WriteLine ( order );
        }
    }
}

public static void HandleSellOrder ( BinanceStreamOrderUpdate data )
{
    if ( data.Status == OrderStatus.Filled || data.Status == OrderStatus.Canceled || data.Status == OrderStatus.New )
    {
        if ( data.QuantityFilled > 0 )
        {
            var pairSymbol = Utility.GetPairSymbol ( data.Symbol );
            if ( pairSymbol != "" )
                MarketData.UpdateStableCoinBalance ( pairSymbol );

            string symbol = Utility.GetBaseSymbol ( data.Symbol );

            var price = Utility.Coins.FirstOrDefault ( c => c.Symbol == symbol )?.Balance.Price;

            var balance = GetBalanceFromAccount ( symbol );
            if ( balance.AvailableAmount * price < 1 )
            {
                Utility.RemoveCoinFromBuyOrderLogs ( symbol );

                var newAction = new UpdateAction ( UpdateType.CoinRemoved, data.Symbol );
                Utility.UpdateActions.Enqueue ( newAction );

                Console.WriteLine ( "{0} : Removed from buy logs", data.Symbol );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can tell from your question you have a number of misconceptions about async/await. But I will ask, do you want a "fire-and-forget" operation? Or do you need these methods to complete before doing something else? Async doesn't make anything go faster, but it can allow something to run in the background. If this is not an ASP.Net application you can Task.Run() your code and move on for fire-and-forget.

Comment: Thanks. Fire and forget basically.

Comment: OK, if you don't have any naturally async operations (which I can't tell for sure, but appears that you do not), then Task.Run() the code. It will run on a thread pool thread. If it were asynchronous code you could run it without `await` and the compiler would tell you about it, but it is not an error if that is really the behavior you want.

Comment: Ok I will run it with task run but there is no difference between that and not awaiting? await confuses me that the program has to wait execution.

Comment: `await` won't block a thread. When `await` is hit the method returns a Task (assuming the task isn't already complete). The thread is available for more work at this point. When the task resolves, then execution starts where it left off at the `await` call. If you don't `await` it behaves similar to Task.Run except [there is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html), so it is typically more efficient than pulling a thread pool thread. It can be useful to call an async function, store the Task in a variable, do some stuff, **then** await the task variable.

Comment: Are the `Utility.HandleBuyOrder(data)` and `Utility.HandleSellOrder(data)` the operations that you want to offload to background threads? If yes, can these operations be executed concurrently by multiple threads, without corrupting the internal state of your program? If not, would you like to serialize these operations so that they are executed sequentially instead of concurrently, or you prefer to modify their implementation so that concurrent executions are thread-safe?

Comment: Thanks guys, @TheodorZoulias: Yes I want to offload them to BG threads. They can execute at the same thing but there is a shared file each function uses one to add new buy orders to it, and the other one removes them. That's why I gathered these operations in a queue data structure, but if these can be done in parallel by avoiding this file then yes that would work also. So right now they execute sequentially. But I am open to modifying it so that they can be run in parallel. Just not sure the best approach.

Comment: @JoanVenge: You almost certainly do **not** want fire-and-forget. "Fire-and-forget" literally means "I don't need to know when this code completes, whether it fails, or handle any results from the code". Instead, use `await Task.Run(() => ...);`

Comment: Hmm. So if I understand correctly the `HandleBuyOrder` and `HandleSellOrder` methods do no perform the actual work of buying and selling orders, but instead they enqueue these actions in some queue. That's quite puzzling to me, for one because there is no mention about the mechanism that actually executes the queued actions, and two because scheduling an operation should be reasonably fast, and should no be itself subject of optimization through offloading. If scheduling is not fast, and it needs to be scheduled itself, then something has gone terribly wrong IMHO.

Comment: @StephenCleary ok I will try this.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Oh yes this app doesn't do trading, it just keeps track of my profits and losses so I am the one doing those actions on the exchange and when a buy or sell happens it shows me these so I can know I dont have coin X anymore or that coin Y is up 30% and the profit is now $200, but after selling half, now it's $100, etc. That's what those handle functions do.

Comment: Ok I changed those handle buy and sell order functions to add to the same queue data structure instead which is handled by a background worker so I guess this should fix it. Adding to that queue shouldnt take much time.